# How do i read a specific line of text from a file and use it as a parameter for a function

Tags: python

I am working on a Python script ( 2.7 ) that will take a line of text from a text file and use it as a parameter for a function but i can not seem to figure out how to pass the line as a parameter for the function
I also was wondering how would i modify a line that already exists in a file without opening it using a text editor within Python

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
data = open("/tmp/INFO.txt", 'r')
Line = data.readlines()[2]
print Line
```

Comment: you can't modify a line in a file without opening the file

Comment: That is not what i mean if you read my question you will see i said modify it from within Python not within a text editor i know about reading/writing to files using open() however i am wondering how would you change data on a line of that file take this for example i have a line of text that say's hello world how would i change this to hello all? sorry for any confusion or if i am coming off rude

Comment: *"...in a file without opening it using a text editor within Python"*. You don't need to open anything in text editor. Run your code and it opens the file, makes the changes and closes it.

Comment: How would i do this?

Comment: @Samatha it may just be me, but I'm struggling to understand what you mean exactly due to your lack of punctuation so forgive me if I misunderstood ... are you asking how to modify a line from a file without opening it in python, or how to modify a line from a file after you've retrieved the line from the file using python?

Comment: Sorry for that but i am asking how do i change a existing line in a file to another piece of text like this i have Hello World how would i change this to Hello All?

Answer (score 2):

To get the specific line:

```py
f = open("yourFile.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()[yourLineNumber]
f.close()
```

To pass it as a parameter:

```py
yourFunction(line)
```

Comment: Do i include my line number in () or [] ?

Comment: @Samatha in [ ]

Comment: I changed the code to represent what you showed but now Python throws Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test8.py", line 3, in <module>
    Line = Data.readlines()[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Samatha it should only be showing one line; can you paste your existing code into your question?

Comment: @Samatha, please be specific on which line you need to pass to function. Add all relevant information into your original question and that avoids further confusions in the comments.

Comment: I added the code to my question i am new to this website so i am not sure how to display the code properly so i just added it

Comment: @Samatha python uses 0-indexing, so `Data.readlines()[2]` is actually the third line, which may be the problem here if it doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding i have added the code i am using to my question i am looking to read line two and print it to the screen however when using the above code Python returns IndexError: list index out of range i have included the full error in a comment above also how would i fix Python going to the third line? Whenever i put two in [] Python throws the already mentioned error however when i put it in () it outputs the entire file

Comment: There are only two lines in this file

Comment: @Samatha as i said above, `Data.readlines()[2]` is actually the third line as python starts at 0, so replace the 2 with 1 and you should be fine

Comment: Alright that worked thank you
#!/usr/bin/python
Read = open("/tmp/INFO.txt", 'r')
Line = Read.readlines()[1]
print Line
Read.close()

Answer (score 0):

To read a specific line and use it as a parameter, you first need to open the file then read the contents.

```
with open(filePath, 'r') as fd:
    fileContents = fd.readlines()
```

Then you can can call `fileContents[n]` where n is the index of the line you need.